# Using intermediate result in backend with node-postgres

Tags: postgresql, node.js

Firstly, I am using the `node-postgres` module to access database in a node application.

I have this SQL code that pulls up data from a table data of which is pulled from another table.

```
SELECT dwa_id
FROM _tasks2dwa
WHERE task_id IN 
(
    SELECT task_id
    FROM _tasks
    WHERE onetsoc_code IN
    (
    SELECT onetsoc_code
    FROM _alternate_titles
    WHERE alternate_title
    ILIKE '%Beta Tester%'
    )
)
```

I would like to use this query like `client.query(query)`(Please refer to the [docs](https://node-postgres.com/)).
I would like to use the intermediate result (the table that is comprised of values of `task_id`) in a backend application. However I also need the end result, the table that is comprised of values of `dwa_id` in that backend application. I have a solution which is writing a separate query for each result, which seems inefficient. Is there another more efficient approach to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to store the intermediate result in a temporary table, but there is no way to avoid the two queries:

```sql
create temporary table temp_result
as
SELECT task_id
FROM _tasks
WHERE onetsoc_code IN 
    (
    SELECT onetsoc_code 
    FROM _alternate_titles 
    WHERE alternate_title ILIKE '%Beta Tester%'
    );
```

Then, using the same (physical) connection to the database, you can run the query to retrieve the intermediate result:

```
select *
from temp_result;
```

And the actual result you want:

```sql
SELECT dwa_id
FROM _tasks2dwa
WHERE task_id IN (select task_id from temp_result);
```

---

If you only want (or get) each `dwa_id` only once, another option is to aggregate the task_ids into an array:

Something along the lines:

```
SELECT td.dwa_id, array_agg(t.task_id) as task_ids
FROM _tasks2dwa td
  JOIN _tasks t on td.task_id = t.task_id
WHERE t.onetsoc_code IN (SELECT alt.onetsoc_code
                         FROM _alternate_titles alt
                         WHERE alt.alternate_title ILIKE '%Beta Tester%'
GROUP BY td.dwa_id;
```